# What to do with Shining Coins?

Tags: bloodborne

I now have half a dozen Shining Coins, which according to info on the internet, purely lights up dark areas. Is there an area I should save these for?

I'm currently in Old Yarnham, but haven't seen a use for them yet. Do they serve any other purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These items can be used as markers to stop you getting lost in certain areas, for example in

> the Forbidden Woods,

which can be a little confusing.

So you might find you need to use them eventually!

Comment: Are they permanent (stay even after death)? And can you also remove them from the ground?

Comment: I don't have any in my inventory to test that for you sorry, and I can't remember for certain if mine remained, but if they're anything like the Prism Stones from Dark Souls that they seem to be a copy of, they will disappear after death, or when you go back to Hunter's Dream and return to the area you were in.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you cannot pick them back up.